# React hook useState isAction is not defined

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

When clicking 'click', setIsAction is undefined. I must miss something obvious. Any idea?

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';

function App() {
  const {isAction, setIsAction} = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isAction) {
      console.log('use effect');
    }
  }, [isAction, setIsAction]);

  return (
    <div
      onClick={() => {
        setIsAction(true);
      }}
    >
      click
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

[full code](https://github.com/kenpeter/use-effect-state)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

useState  returns an array with 2 items. You are trying object destructuring, but it must be [array destructuring](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html#tip-what-do-square-brackets-mean).

```
const [isAction, setIsAction] = useState(false);
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
const {isAction, setIsAction} = useState(false);
```

To

```
 const [isAction, setIsAction] = useState(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';

function App() {
  # need to change here just
  const [isAction, setIsAction] = useState(false); 

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isAction) {
      console.log('use effect');
    }
  }, [isAction, setIsAction]);

  return (
    <div
      onClick={() => {
        setIsAction(true);
      }}
    >
      click
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are destructuring instead useState return array with 2 items. Change this :

```
const {isAction, setIsAction} = useState(false);
```

to

```
const [isAction, setIsAction] = useState(false);
```

Ex :

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';

function App() {
  const [isAction, setIsAction] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isAction) {
      console.log('use effect');
    }
  }, [isAction, setIsAction]);

  return (
    <div
      onClick={() => {
        setIsAction(true);
      }}
    >
      click
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I have modified your example to get better context . You can found demo here : https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-stfhm5